# How can I record the voice of each individual in a separate channel?

Tags: audio-recording

I conduct focus group discussions. I'm looking for a recorder that records the voice of each participants in a separate channel, so that I can analyse each participant separately.

Currently I get all the voices recorded in a single channel and I can't separate them. So basically I would like to know who has said what.

Also, the format should be either FLAC or LINEAR16 while recording.

Comment: The easiest is probably to give each participant their own microphone ...